# Removing empty paragraph tags

Tags: c#, css, vb.net

I would like to find the simplest way to trim the empty

tags before any text starts. for example i have the below text.

```
<p> </p><p> </p>
<p> </p><p>     </p>
<p>    </p>
<p>This is an example<br></p><p> </p><p>continue </p>
```

I would like the output to be `<p>This is an example<br></p><p> </p><p>continue </p>`

I want all the empty P tags to be removed. There can be more than one space between

tags.

I have the options to use CSS or VB or c#.

Comment: And why is this tagged c# then?

Comment: I have no problem converting C# to VB. If you have solution using c# then I would convert it to vb.edited the question

Comment: I've given you an answer with C# then and tried to translate it to Vb myself.

Comment: @Rad see my answer. Its gives you what you want :)

Answer (score 6):

You have tagged your question in css. So, I'm providing you an answer in css using [:empty pseudo class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty):

```
p:empty{
  display: none;
}
```

See [can I use :empty](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

---

As per your updated question:

you can use [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153201/contents-inside-p-element-wraps-outside-the-element) like below:

```
p:empty :not(p + p:empty){
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is hide all the P tags. I would like to remove the one which is preceding any text. I have modified the example.

Comment: There is no P tag nested

Comment: This does not remove tags if they contain whitespace. This functionality is introduced in the spec for css selectors level 4 (see [can i use :empty matches whitespace](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_empty_matches_whitespace)). Currently (August 2023) no browser supports this.

Answer (score 4):

Give your comment, that you also accept C# I'd suggest using a simple regular expression to validate this:

```
var source = @"<p> </p><p> </p>
<p> </p><p>     </p>
<p>    </p>
<p>This is an example<br></p><p> </p><p>continue </p>";

string output = Regex.Replace(source, @"<p>\s*</p>", "").Trim();
```

The same code in VB.net converted with Telerik should look like this:

```
Dim source = "<p> </p><p> </p>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<p> </p><p>     </p>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<p>    </p>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<p>This is an example<br></p><p> </p><p>continue </p>"

Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(source, "<p>\s*</p>", "").Trim()
```

Explanation:

```
<p> matches the characters <p> literally
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ] 0 to unlimited times
</p> matches the characters </p> literally
```

Answer (score 0):

using **jQuery, NOT c#, vb.net or CSS**

write this on document ready event

```
var p = $("p"); 

    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
   { 
       if($.trim(p[i].innerHTML) == "")
        {
          p[i].remove();
         }
    }
```

1. Find all P tag
2. iterate over them to find empty tags
3. remove them

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxt4kn17/)

Answer (score -1):

I think this css trick will work:

```
p:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: isnt a single space considered not empty?

Comment: no, it will be considered as empty. empty selector matches every element that has no children (including text nodes).

Comment: I want to remove the empty nodes that exist only before a text starts. Not all the empty paragraph

Comment: As @Mox says: This does not remove tags if they contain whitespace. This functionality is introduced in the spec for css selectors level 4 (see [can i use :empty matches whitespace](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_empty_matches_whitespace)). Currently (August 2023) no browser supports this.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
   function removeEmptyPTags() {            
                var items = $('body').find('p');
                $.each(items, function (i, v) {
                    if ($(items[i]).html().trim() === "") {
                        $(items[i]).remove();
                    }
                });
            }
```